# CSS-zoomed page appear differently than user-zoomed page appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I think my page looks good when it is zoomed to 90%, then I tried this:

```
body{
   zoom:90%;
}
```

but the result is different, with css it leaves gap at the bottom section while user-zoomed just looks fine.
[image]

i did also tried with `transform:scale(0.9)` but not only it gives gap at the bottom but also at the right side of the page.

so how can I achieve the same appearance?

I'm also using vuetify, maybe there's something useful

Comment: I just wondering why you want to do like that? @idris

Comment: @Rafv in 100% the entire page looks so big, in 90% it feels just right

Answer (score 0):

CSS zoom isn't going to be like browser zoom, the contents on the screen will go to 90% size rather than being resized by the browser which will adjust fonts but keep the table position from the bottom the same. If you want to really do this, try adjusting just the font size and not the size of the window - That's not really great practise and is going to look worse when the screen gets smaller

Comment: is there any way other than adjusting every element to match that appearance? maybe javascript?